# Why is it hard to compute $g^{xy}\bmod p$ from $g^x\bmod p$ and $g^y\bmod p$?

Tags: diffie-hellman

Why is it hard to compute $$(g^x\bmod p, g^y\bmod p) \longmapsto g^{xy}\bmod p $$
when can we quickly compute
$$x \longmapsto g^x\bmod p$$
?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the relation between Discrete Log, Computational Diffie-Hellman and Decisional Diffie-Hellman?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/what-is-the-relation-between-discrete-log-computational-diffie-hellman-and-deci) and [Discrete Logarithm: Given a p, what does it mean to find the discrete logarithm of x to base y?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76230/18298)

Comment: The present question is not really a dupe of [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1493/555), but the later's [accepted answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1498/555) covers the present question to a large degree. Short answer: because we do not know an efficient method. Fact: one method would be to find $x$ and use $g^{xy}\bmod p\ =\ (g^y\bmod p)^x\bmod p$, but we do not know an efficient method to compute $x$ from $g^x\bmod p$.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you are asking a question about DH exchanging key protocol.
In DH, `A` creates a random private key of `x` and then will send the `mod` to `B`.
so nobody knows the `X`, although everyone can see the `mod` they cannot get the `x` from it, because of DLP (Discrete Logarithm Problem).

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: A bit more going into depth would have helped here, you could have explained that you'd need $x$ to calculate $(g^x\bmod p, g^y\bmod p) \longmapsto g^{xy}\bmod p$ I suppose. As it stands, just saying that DH is considered secure because of DLP doesn't really touch the question at hand. That said, a bit more direction could have helped instead of just downvotes and negative comments.