# On access to a Diffie Hellman oracle

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, prime-numbers, group-theory, number-theory

Assume $g$ is generator of multiplicative group modulo prime $p$.

Assume we know $g^X\bmod p$ and $g^{XY}\bmod p$ and assume we can have access to a Diffie-Hellman oracle.

> Can we find $g^Y\bmod p$ in polynomial time?

If we know how to compute $g^{X^{-1}}\bmod p$ then we can use the oracle to compute $g^Y\bmod P$.

So I believe the problem reduces to computation of $g^{X^{-1}}\bmod p$ given a Diffie-Hellman oracle.

Comment: I'm not really following what you want to achive. [What is the relation between Discrete Log, Computational Diffie-Hellman and Decisional Diffie-Hellman?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1493/18298). Do you want this to show that given $g^x$ and $g^{xy}$  if we can find then this is equivalent to CDH?

Comment: HINT: Your Diffie-Hellman oracle takes inputs $(h,h^a,h^b)$and returns $h^{ab}$. Try using $g^x$ as the first argument.

Comment: @kelalaka I just want to find $g^Y\bmod p$ using cdh.

Comment: @daniels I don't follow but if you know the answer please write below.

Comment: Before I write the answer, can I be assured that this is not an assignment?

Comment: find the inverse of $(g^x)^{-1}$ and send the CDH oracle to cancel?

Comment: Note that, for such a question, one can write an oracle for small-sized $p$ so that they can test their argument. For example, for CDH write a function that finds a discrete log of $g^x$  and $g^y$ and returns  $g^{xy}$ ( choose $p$ small! to find the dlog with brute force. Now you can test your arguments ( together with dlog function )

Comment: @DanielS No it is not a hw.

Comment: Then what is the source of this question?

Comment: Just a natural thought ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are equipped with a function which takes three inputs $\mathrm{CDH}(h,h^a,h^b)$ that returns $h^{ab}$. We call it with the inputs $\mathrm{CDH}(g^x,g,g^{xy})$. If we write $a$ for the residue mod $p-1$ such that $ax\equiv 1\pmod{p-1}$ we see that if we define $h$ to be $g^x\mod p$ then $h^a=g^{ax}=g\mod p$ and $h^y=g^{xy}\mod p$. Thus for this choice of $h$ we have $\mathrm{CDH}(g^x,g,g^{xy})=\mathrm{CDH}(h,h^a,h^y)=h^{ay}=g^{axy}=g^y\mod p$.

There is a slight wrinkle when $x$ is not invertible mod $p-1$, for in this case $y$ is not uniquely defined by $g^{xy}$. To be precise, if $\mathrm{GCD}(x,p-1)=\ell$ then all of the values $y'=y+k\ell$ for $k=1,\ldots (p-1)/\ell$ would all have $g^{xy}=g^{xy'}\mod p$ so that $g^{y'}$ would be a legitimate answer fo any of the $y'$.

Our CDH oracle may be defined in such a way as not to accept $g$ as  second argument in the case where $h=g^x$ and $x$ has a common factor with $p-1$, because $g$ does not lie in $\langle h\rangle$. In such cases we can take arbitrary $\ell$th roots of $g^x$ and $g^{xy}$ and use these as the second and third arguments and proceed as before but noting the multiple possible answers.

As an amusing aside, if we have the public values and shared secret for a Diffie-Hellman exchange, but do not know the generator (i.e. we know $g^x$, $g^y$ and $g^{xy}$ but not $g$), then such an oracle can recover $g$ since $\mathrm{CDH}(g^{xy},g^x,g^y)=g$.

Comment: Nice... so we do not need to find $g^{X^{-1}}\bmod p$ at all? For computing $g^{X^{-1}}\bmod p$ you pass in $(g^X,g,g)$ which is $(h,h^{X^{-1}},h^{X^{-1}})$ to get $h^{X^{-2}}\bmod p$ which is $g^{X^{-1}}\bmod p$?

Comment: Correct. The approach of the answer is more direct, but your method also works.

Comment: Why $g^{xy}=g^{xy'}$? How is $g^{xk\ell}=1\bmod p$ if $k\neq(p-1)$?

Comment: Does this work for elliptic curves as well?